Async-friendly RefCell that prevents borrow across await points
Is there any way to create a RefCell-like data structure that prevents a borrow from being held across an await point? I have a single-threaded async runtime and the internal state of my object is safe to mutate within a single thread. However, RefCell is dangerous because if I accidentally hold the borrow across an await point it's no longer safe for the caller to have overlapping calls into the mutating API which is actually safe (they'll panic because of duplicate borrows).
I imagine a similar problem must exist with Mutex + work-stealing runtimes.
I'm guessing I could have a RefCell wrapper that only ever exposes a closure-based interface:
fn guarded_mut<F: FnOnce(&mut T)>(&self, cb: F)

but if I want to be able to easily forward return values out of it, I'm not sure how to safely guard against futures:
fn guarded_mut<R, F: FnOnce(&mut T) -> R>(&self, cb: F) -> R

guarded_mut(|interior| async move {
}).await;

Maybe the guarded API just works to prevent this because the lifetime of the interior is shorter than the lifetime of R?

I don't understand, is the problem that it will panic at runtime?

Yes, it's really easy to write innocuous looking code that will panic instead of being structurally inhibited from having that property.


I'm guessing I could have a RefCell wrapper that only ever exposes a closure-based interface

That is an excellent approach.

but if I want to be able to easily forward return values out of it, I'm not sure how to safely guard against futures

If the future captures the borrowed value, it won't compile:
pub struct GuardedRefCell<T: ?Sized>(std::cell::RefCell<T>);

impl<T> GuardedRefCell<T> {
    pub const fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self(std::cell::RefCell::new(value))
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> GuardedRefCell<T> {
    pub fn guarded_ref<R, F: FnOnce(&T) -> R>(&self, f: F) -> R {
        f(&mut self.0.borrow())
    }
    
    pub fn guarded_mut<R, F: FnOnce(&mut T) -> R>(&self, f: F) -> R {
        f(&mut self.0.borrow_mut())
    }
}

async fn foo(cell: &GuardedRefCell<i32>) {
    cell.guarded_ref(|v| async move { dbg!(*v); }).await;
}

Playground.
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:20:26
   |
20 |     cell.guarded_ref(|v| async move { dbg!(*v); }).await;
   |                       -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                       ||
   |                       |return type of closure `{async block@src/lib.rs:20:26: 20:50}` contains a lifetime `'2`
   |                       has type `&'1 i32`

Thread locals' with() relies on this to be sound.

No, my potential solution doesn't actually work:
let some_safe_object = AsyncCell::::default();
some_safe_object.borrow().async_member().await;
The async function requires the borrow to be held even though it only needs to be held within the poll. The only solution I can think of is to get rid of async & to implement all the futures by hand by grabbing the references to the interior refcell & borrowing for the duration of the future. But that doesn't scale because that quickly runs into problems as soon as my custom future then needs to call an async function.

@Vitali Why not?

Hit the wrong button - updated the comment.

@Vitali Well, the entire point was disallowing .awaits, no?

I still need to be able to call async methods on what's being borrowed but having the borrow drop out except when being polled.

I guess I could have an with_async_borrow(|inner| async move { do stuff with inner}).await such that with_async_borrow captures the returned Future of the callback & returns a custom future that borrows the interior appropriately?

@Vitali I don't understand. Your question was how to disallow .awaits within borrows, no? So you got an answer. What is the problem?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
